# React Native: Assigning value with setState()

Tags: reactjs, react-native, setstate

Here, props name in the handler function is the same as the name in state, both are `phone'

```
state = {
    phone: '',
  }
```

.

```
<TextInput
          onChangeText={this.handlePhoneChange}
        />
```

.

```
handlePhoneChange = phone => {
    this.setState({phone})
  }
```

shouldn't it be `this.setState({phone:phone})`? are the two statements synonymous or am I missing something?

Comment: They are fairly synonymous. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Property_definitions can help explain. It's just a short-hand way of defining object literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> New in JavaScript with ES6/ES2015, if you want to define an object
>   who's keys have the same name as the variables passed-in as
>   properties, you can use the shorthand and simply pass the key name.

That is short syntax for ,

```
{phone : phone}
```

if key name is same as variable name you can use it like :

```
{phone}
```

**[ALSO DO READ](https://alligator.io/js/object-property-shorthand-es6/)**